# Adding items to a list using regex to search for the correct header

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list that I originally had taken from a CSV file and saved to a list. The csv file was originally an excel sheet that had categories with data for each one. I have had trouble trying to extract the header and the content along with it in an organized fashion. the list looks like this

```
myLoad =[
['Unit 1000', '', '']
['A1', 'Food', 'Good']
['A3', 'Drink', 'Poor']
['A6', 'Food', '']
['Unit 1001',  '', '']
['A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow']
['A8', 'Coke', 'Brown] ]
```

and I would want the list to look something like

```
1000, A1, Food, Good
1000, A3, Drink, Poor
1000, A6, Food, 
1001, A7, Cheese, Yellow
1001, A8, Coke, Brown
```

Although there was another list I was comparing it to to extract data from, I was using regex to find the Unit number, but even after being able to find the number I was unable to extract the rest of the list with each category number to go with it.What I had so far was.

```
loadRegex = re.compile(r'\d{4}')

for i, row in enumerate(myLoad):
  thisLoad = loadRegex.search(row[0])
  if thisLoad:
    print thisLoad.group() #which would print each number
```

---

After this I couldnt figure out
how I could get Unit # to print (and eventually append to anew list), and the content below it for each section as if it all went together.

I wanted the content to be like if the Unit # is found then print each row until the next unit # is found, but it has to be based on the regex so that I can use the same regex to compare the same unit number to another file

Comment: I advice you to use dictinaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't use a `regex` here.

```
myLoad =[
    ['Unit 1000', '', ''],
    ['A1', 'Food', 'Good'],
    ['A3', 'Drink', 'Poor'],
    ['A6', 'Food', ''],
    ['Unit 1001',  '', ''],
    ['A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow'],
    ['A8', 'Coke', 'Brown'] ]

lst = []
for x in myLoad:
    if x[0].startswith('Unit'):
        unit = x[0].split()[1]
        continue   
    lst.extend([[unit] + x])   # or lst.append([unit] + x)

print(lst)

# [['1000', 'A1', 'Food', 'Good'], 
#  ['1000', 'A3', 'Drink', 'Poor'], 
#  ['1000', 'A6', 'Food', ''], 
#  ['1001', 'A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow'], 
#  ['1001', 'A8', 'Coke', 'Brown']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, just simply do the below code:

```
myLoad =[
['Unit 1000', '', ''],
['A1', 'Food', 'Good'],
['A3', 'Drink', 'Poor'],
['A6', 'Food', ''],
['Unit 1001',  '', ''],
['A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow'],
['A8', 'Coke', 'Brown']]
unit = 0
for i in myLoad:
   if 'Unit' not in i[0]:
      print(', '.join([unit,i[0],i[1],i[2]]))
   else:
      unit = i[0].split()[-1]
```

Output:

```
1000, A1, Food, Good
1000, A3, Drink, Poor
1000, A6, Food, 
1001, A7, Cheese, Yellow
1001, A8, Coke, Brown
```

Comment: It's not a desired answer. please look the first column. 1001 should come in last two rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this problem by pandas version,
You could try this,

```
df= pd.DataFrame(myLoad)
df.loc[df[1]=='','new']=df[0].str.strip('Unit ')
df['new']=df['new'].fillna(method='ffill')
df=df[['new',0,1,2]]
df=df[df[1]!='']
print df.values
```

Output:

```
[['1000' 'A1' 'Food' 'Good']
 ['1000' 'A3' 'Drink' 'Poor']
 ['1000' 'A6' 'Food' '']
 ['1001' 'A7' 'Cheese' 'Yellow']
 ['1001' 'A8' 'Coke' 'Brown']]
```

Explanation:

1. Convert your list to DataFrame.
2. create a new column for unit values. fill NaN values by forward fill method.
3. extract required rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
from pprint import pprint

myLoad =[
    ['Unit 1000', '', ''],
    ['A1', 'Food', 'Good'],
    ['A3', 'Drink', 'Poor'],
    ['A6', 'Food', ''],
    ['Unit 1001',  '', ''],
    ['A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow'],
    ['A8', 'Coke', 'Brown']]

result = []
unit = None
for load in myLoad:
    if load[0].startswith('Unit'):
        _, unit = load[0].split()
    elif unit:
        result.append([unit] + load)

pprint(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[['1000', 'A1', 'Food', 'Good'],
 ['1000', 'A3', 'Drink', 'Poor'],
 ['1000', 'A6', 'Food', ''],
 ['1001', 'A7', 'Cheese', 'Yellow'],
 ['1001', 'A8', 'Coke', 'Brown']]
```